# Java Swing - mouse pointer "shifted" on context menu when JFrame is maximized

Tags: linux, swing, java

I encoutered a strange behaviour of handling mouse position by Swing when maximizing JFrame:

When I execute this very simple code...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
                menu.add(new JMenuItem("New"));
                menubar.add(menu);
                frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

... I can normally click `File` (first click - press,release) -> `New` (second click). But when I maximize JFrame and click on `File` - context menu disappears on mouse release immediately. 
Moreover when I hold mouse button - to prevent disappearance - I must move my mouse much further to focus on `New` item.

[image: mouse shift]

The red dot represents area (more or less) where I must move my mouse to focus on `New` after pressing `File` and holding mouse button.

I've observed the same behaviour when using "right-click context menu" for example when right clicking on chart from JFreeChart.

I thought it was JDK problem because I used Oracle's JDK, but after installing OpenJDK I have the same results.

Did somebody observe this strange behaviour? Or am I missing something obvious?

I use:

- 1.7.0_147-icedtea (or 1.7.0_04 for java-7-oracle)
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.0) (7~b147-2.0-0ubuntu0.11.10.1)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
- Linux Mint 12 (lisa) GNOME 3.2.1

Comment: Seems to me, it's just a bug of Java 7, nothing else, try to come back to any previous version and it's not there, Java 7 has many bugs, like the one you just referred :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this is a bug in JDK7 as @nIcE cOw mentioned.

I've installed JDK6 and I couldn't reproduce this bug.

```
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also a workaround when it is necessary to use the Oracle Java 7 (e.g. when using JavaFX). Just add the following lines of code to your window/frame class:

```
        if (Arrays.asList("gnome-shell", "mate", "other...").contains(System.getenv("DESKTOP_SESSION"))) {
        try {
            Class<?> xwm = Class.forName("sun.awt.X11.XWM");
            Field awt_wmgr = xwm.getDeclaredField("awt_wmgr");
            awt_wmgr.setAccessible(true);
            Field other_wm = xwm.getDeclaredField("OTHER_WM");
            other_wm.setAccessible(true);
            if (awt_wmgr.get(null).equals(other_wm.get(null))) {
                Field metacity_wm = xwm.getDeclaredField("METACITY_WM");
                metacity_wm.setAccessible(true);
                awt_wmgr.set(null, metacity_wm.get(null));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code snippet is based on a [workaround from the Netbeans developers](http://hg.netbeans.org/core-main/rev/409566c2aa65).

Comment: It sets the current AWT window manager class to the class used for the Metacity WM if the the desktop session is a Gnome Shell or Mate session.

Comment: Okay. So why does it check the value of OTHER_WM?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to complement the solution given by problemzebra.

As it still happens for me with any swing application on Linux (using Cinnamon desktop), even on Java 6 (update 45)

The issue will reoccur every time I move the window or resize it, so you need to reapply the workaround every time the window changes. I created the following class and use it whenever I create a new window:

```
class LinuxWindowFix implements WindowStateListener {

    private final String desktop;
    private Field metacity_wm;
    private Field awt_wmgr;
    private boolean applyFix;

    private static LinuxWindowFix instance = new LinuxWindowFix();

    public static LinuxWindowFix getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private LinuxWindowFix() {
        applyFix = false;

        List<String> linuxDesktops = Arrays.asList("gnome-shell", "mate", "cinnamon"); //add more desktop names here.

        desktop = System.getenv("DESKTOP_SESSION");
        if (desktop != null && linuxDesktops.contains(desktop.toLowerCase())) {
            try {
                Class<?> xwm = Class.forName("sun.awt.X11.XWM");
                awt_wmgr = xwm.getDeclaredField("awt_wmgr");
                awt_wmgr.setAccessible(true);
                Field other_wm = xwm.getDeclaredField("OTHER_WM");
                other_wm.setAccessible(true);
                if (awt_wmgr.get(null).equals(other_wm.get(null))) {
                    metacity_wm = xwm.getDeclaredField("METACITY_WM");
                    metacity_wm.setAccessible(true);
                    applyFix = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //ignore
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
        try {
            awt_wmgr.set(null, metacity_wm.get(null));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //ignore
        }
    }

    public void apply(Window w) {
        if (!applyFix) {
            return;
        }
        w.removeWindowStateListener(this);
        w.addWindowStateListener(this);
    }
}
```

Simply call this for every window you create and it will work as expected.

```
LinuxWindowFix.getInstance().apply(myWindow);
```